# Adding data to an Access table

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

My application reads a scale through a comport and does some logic. I then want it to output 6 readings to an Access database:

- date/time time twice
- status
- Layer count
- Part count
- scale weight

I pulled this code from online and the statement `dbInsert.ExcuteNonQuery ()` gets the error

> data type mismatch in criteria expression

Code:

```vb
Dim dbInsert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim dbConnect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim Line As String = Environment.NewLine
Dim Status As String
Dim Stamp As Date
Dim pc As Double
Dim lc As Double

Sub AddToDb ()
    Try
        dbConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Test\Test_be.accdb"
        dbConnect.Open()
        dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Date_Stamp"
        dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Date_Stamp").Value = Stamp
        dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Time_Stamp"
        dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Time_Stamp").Value = Stamp
        dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Status"
        dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Status").Value = Status
        dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Layer_Count"
        dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Layer_Count").Value = lc
        dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Part_Count"
        dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Part_Count").Value = pc
        dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Weight"
        dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Weight").Value = WeightAConvert
        Try
            dbInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Log VALUES (Stamp,Stamp, Status, lc, pc, WeightAConvert);"
            dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
            dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Updated code:

```
Try

        Dim SQL = "INSERT INTO Scale_Log (Date_Stamp,Time_Stamp, Status, Layer_Count, Part_Count, Weight) VALUES (Stamp,Stamp,Status,lc,pc,WeightAConvert)"

        Using dbCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Test\Line_6&7_Weight_Log_be.accdb")

            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, dbCon)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Date_Stamp", OleDbType.Date).Value = Stamp
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Time_Stamp", OleDbType.Date).Value = Stamp
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Status", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Status
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Lay_Count", OleDbType.Double).Value = lc
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Part_Count", OleDbType.Double).Value = pc
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Weight", OleDbType.Double).Value = WeightAConvert
                dbCon.Open()
                Dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
            End Using

            dbCon.Close()

            dbCon.Dispose()

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

Comment: Your SQL doesnt do anything to map values to columns. If the DB doesnt return the columns in that order you will be trying to put some things into the wring column.  The SQL should have the params in it, not the variables  (`"Date_Stamp"` rather than `Stamp`) that would matter with other DB providers.  Also, turn on Option Strict - `layerCount` and some others are not declared in code we can see

Comment: @Plutonix Im not really getting what your saying, youre saying change what in `dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Date_Stamp"   dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Date_Stamp").Value = Stamp` and this is a snip out of 2000 lines of code, the LayerCount is declared else where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying the columns in the SQL so you have no control over which variable is mapped to what database column.  It will work when you just happen to add the Parameters in the right order.  Dont leave it to chance: when it is wrong you can get a data mismatch error.

Also, it appears that you are using a global `DBConnection` and `DBCommand` object.  **Don't do that** as it can result in all sorts of problems:

- Fundamentally, a DBCommand object is query-specific so it has no re-use value
- The next time you go to use that command object it will already have 6 parameters defined in it.  This can result in too many parameters for the next time.
- Since the DBCommand object requires a reference to the connection (`dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect` in your code), by not disposing of it, you are also not closing or disposing of that connection.

And of course, if the type of data passed does not match the db column type, it can result in data type mismatch.  You want something like this:

```vb
Dim SQL = "INSERT INTO [Log] (colA, colB, colC...) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"

' dont use global provider objects
Using dbCon As New OleDbConnection(ACEConnStr)   ' use YOUR connection string
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, dbCon)

        ' do these in the exact same order as the cols are listed in the SQL
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = Stamp       ' colA
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = Stamp       ' colB
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Status
        '...
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Double).Value = ItemWeight 'colF
        dbCon.Open()
        Dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

- First, `Log` may be a reserved word in Access-SQL, so I escaped the name<sup>1</sup>.  The columns and their order is specified in the SQL statement.
- The `?,?,?,?` list in the SQL are placeholders.  You can also use `@p1, @p2,@p3...` or even names, but `OleDB` will use them by position only (read on).
- The data for each is provided with each `cmd.Parameters.Add("?",...` statement. This is how your code maps/provides the value for each parameter in the SQL.
- A `DateTime` column will have both the date and time.  I am not sure why you store them separately.
- With other Providers they map the value based on the Parameter name (`cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", ...).Value = myFirstNameVar`).  OleDB doesnt use named parameters as such, so you **must** provide the parameter values in **the exact same order** as the column names appear in the SQL.
- The `Using` blocks **create** the target objects for you to use, then close and dispose of them at the end.  Your connectionstring can be a global variable.

Finally, rather than global vars for things like `layercount` consider passing them:

```vb
Sub AddToDb(foo As String, Stamp As DateTime, lc As Double....)
```

<sup>1. I am not sure that is actually true in this case, [but it is on a list](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)</sup>

See also: **[Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) on MSDN**